# How to have a glyphicon in a Bootstrap stateful button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap stateful button with a glyphicon:

```
<button type="button" data-deleting-text="Deleting..." class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete
</button>
```

But when I enable the state in my JS:

```
$target.button('deleting');
```

the text changes correctly and the button disables, but the icon also disappears. This is understandable, since I guess Bootstrap is just replacing the content of the button.

How to I make my button retain its icon? I'm really hoping the right answer here isn't to embed another copy of the `<span>` element into the `data-deleting-text` attribute because that would suck a lot!

Comment: How about removing span and applying the class to the button itself? [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1513/)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I tried that. Unfortunately the results weren't great. Partly because the glyphicons are implemented as a font (I think this is new in Bootstrap 3). I could get around that by wrapping the text in a `<span>` to put the font back to normal, but then I'm back to square one - enabling the state will cause the `<span>` to be removed.

Comment: `$('button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Deleting'); ` It sucks, But you should do that..

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, my first idea was to put the `<span>` element into the data attribute :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-deleting-text="&lt;span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'&gt;&lt;/span&gt; Deleting...">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
</button>
```

But you've got another option : put your `.glyphicon` class on the button, and override Bootstrap CSS to get it working well :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-deleting-text="&nbsp;Deleting...">&nbsp;Delete</button>
```

```
.btn.glyphicon { // override .glyphicon style if it's set on a .btn
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
}
.btn.glyphicon::first-letter { // keep the Glyphicon font for the first letter
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    line-height: 1;
}
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/104049)

*Note: `::first-letter` works only for >=IE9*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the text in a span and target it with a given ID or class?

```
<button type="button" data-deleting-text="Deleting..." class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    <span class="button-text">Delete</span>
</button>
```